# How to programaticly scroll down a UITable

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, ios

Im implementing a bubble chat using a UITable,
and I want the table to scroll down every time someone posts a message.
Is it possible to make the table view to scroll down?
How do  i do that?

Comment: nice, I also want to get this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will probably want to call this method:

```
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```